# Firebase Cloud Functions - The request was aborted because there was no available instance

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

After deploying the function, I got this intermittent error several times.

> Error: Server Error
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
> Please try again in 30 seconds.

The error log also shows `"The request was aborted because there was no available instance."`

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/962

Comment: I'm getting this error today as well. Suddenly all cloud functions return 500 "The request was aborted because there was no available instance" on my test server. Production continue to work though. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the [error](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#scalability) occurs when the Cloud Function infrastructure is not able to scale up instances fast enough to handle the incoming load. Hence, the requests get aborted as no instance becomes available to serve the requests.

This could be due to the following conditions:

- A huge sudden increase in traffic.
- A long cold start time.
- A long request processing time.
- High function error rate.
- Reaching the maximum instance limit and hence the system cannot scale any further.
- Transient factors attributed to the Cloud Functions service.

To mitigate the issue, you can configure the [minimum instances](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/min-instances) other than 0 for the Cloud Function to avoid cold start and make sure there are instances ready to serve the requests. However, note that setting the minimum instances will incur additional [charges](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing).

Comment: If i calculate correctly am I looking at around $6 a month per instance I keep active?  How do I know the number of instances needed?  I assume it's not 1 instance per task.  Any workaround without needing min instances?